# Call Table Valued Function in LINQ query without .edmx

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio, linq-to-sql

I have created a Table Valued Function in SQL.

I need to be able to call this function within my LINQ queries. I do not use the `.edmx` approach, I have a context class. My current version of Entity Framework is `Version 6.0.0.0`

All the examples I have seen so far is using the `.edmx` approach.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could use `SQLQuery<T>` method on the `Database` class to execute your TVF:

```
int id = 1;
var query = context.Database.SqlQuery<Person>("Select * from [dbo].[tfn_GetPersonInfo](@p0)", id);
var results = query.ToList();
```

### Update

Digging deep in this matter I found this [article](https://blog.3d-logic.com/2014/04/09/support-for-store-functions-tvfs-and-stored-procs-in-entity-framework-6-1/) that could help you to find the solution you are trying to achieve. You can find the nuget package you need to install in this [link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.CodeFirstStoreFunctions)

Comment: I would have taken this approach, but this does not return IQueryable<>, so I cannot use this within a LINQ Query that will have to CROSS APPLY with the Table Valued Function.

Comment: Seems to be doing what I want it to do.  I find it strange that this is not implemented by default with Entity Framework. Thanks